# Trigger Error: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded

Tags: apex, trigger, governorlimits, cpulimit

The below code searches on the lead record if the Account already exists in Salesforce using the website/email domain field. The code works just fine but I keep getting this error in my inbox: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded

```
Trigger Accname on Lead (before insert, before update) { 

    Account[] accts = [SELECT Name, id,Website,Domain__c FROM Account WHERE (Website != NULL OR Domain__c != NULL)];
    for(Lead l : Trigger.new)
    {        
        for(Integer i = 0; i < accts.size(); i++)
        {
            if(l.Domain__c == accts[i].Domain__c ||  l.Domain__c == accts[i].Website)
            {
                l.Account_Leads__c = accts[i].id;
                l.Account_Found__c = True;

            } else(System.debug('Not triggered.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many accounts do you have?

Comment: Some background on the problem [Fixing a common cause of System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded](https://force201.wordpress.com/2014/11/09/fixing-a-common-cause-of-system-limitexception-apex-cpu-time-limit-exceeded/).

Answer (score 11):

Try at least restricting to `Account` records which might match, and mapping by those values.

```
public with sharing class LeadService
{
    public static void findAccountsByDomain(List<Lead> newRecords)
    {
        Set<String> domains = new Set<String>();
        for (Lead record : newRecords) domains.add(record.Domain__c);
        Map<String, Account> domainToAccount = new Map<String, Account>();
        for (Account record : [
            SELECT Website, Domain__c FROM Account
            WHERE Website IN :domains OR Domain__c IN :domains
        ]){
            domainToAccount.put(safeLowerCase(record.Website), record);
            domainToAccount.put(safeLowerCase(record.Domain__c), record);
        }
        domainToAccount.remove(null);

        for (Lead record : newRecords)
        {
            Account parent = domainToAccount.get(safeLowerCase(record.Domain__c));
            if (parent != null)
            {
                record.Account_Leads__c = parent.Id;
                record.Account_Found__c = true;
            }
        }
    }
    static String safeLowerCase(String input)
    {
        return input == null ? input : input.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Then in your trigger you would call `LeadService.findAccountsByDomain(trigger.new);`.

Note that you may have multiple records that match the same key, but you are arbitrarily choosing one. This means your code is not deterministic. You should also look up **[trigger handlers](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)** and find a pattern that works for you to implement logic-less triggers.

Comment: In the line record.Account_Leads__c = record.Id, it is mapping the lead id to the lead record. How to map the account id to that field?

Comment: Just change to `record.Account_Leads__c = domainToAccount.get(record.Domain__c).Id;`

Comment: @Mike N.B. map keys will be case sensitive so application should ensure that Account.Website, Account.Domain__c,  Lead.Domain__c are all the same case (presumably lower) - otherwise `Account parent = domainToAccount.get(record.Domain__c);` will not always work

Comment: The domain could also be null though, so you have to account for that too. I'll update though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting my edit as a separate answer:

Besides the minor edit that I have made, the suggested solution from Adrian seems to solve your problem, where is used map collection (their primary use to solve these use cases)

```
Set<String> domains = new Set<String>();
for (Lead record : trigger.new) 
    domains.add(record.Domain__c);
Map<String, Account> domainToAccount = new Map<String, Account>();
for (Account record : [
    SELECT Website, Domain__c FROM Account
    WHERE Website IN :domains OR Domain__c IN :domains
]){
    domainToAccount.put(record.Website, record);
    domainToAccount.put(record.Domain__c, record);
}

for (Lead record : trigger.new)
{
    if (domainToAccount.containsKey(record.Domain__c))
    {
        record.Account_Leads__c = domainToAccount.get(record.Domain__c).Id; // edit, based on the logic of question
        record.Account_Found__c = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked in Sandbox but I am unable to deploy in production due to code coverage error. What would the test class for this trigger be?

Comment: well, check this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_code_coverage_intro.htm, it has the relevant info about testing and code coverage.